# Как заблокировать изменение размера окна Windows в Go

Tags: windows, golang

Как можно заблокировать изменение размера окна Windows в Go с lxn/walk.
Вроде как можно это сделать через установку флагов, но нигде не нашёл примера как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно импортировать пакет `github.com/lxn/win` и использовать его метод `SetWindowLong`как это показано в примере ниже

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/lxn/win"
    "github.com/lxn/walk"
)


func main() {

    var mw, err = walk.NewMainWindow()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer mw.Dispose()

    win.SetWindowLong(
        mw.Handle(),
        win.GWL_STYLE,
        win.WS_CAPTION|win.WS_SYSMENU|win.WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
    )

    mw.SetSize(walk.Size{440, 785})

   // stuff here


    mw.Show()
    os.Exit(mw.Run())
}
```

Стили окна описаны в [документации Microsoft (*англ.*)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-styles) или, например, на русском на [firststeps](http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/detail/r.php?24).

---

Есть ещё вариант использовать `Dialog` как в [этом примере](https://github.com/lxn/walk/issues/472)

Comment: У меня этот код вообще не работает т.е. он собирается без ошибок но приложение ничего не выводит

Comment: @pnp2000, оно и не должно. Ниже допишите код который будет показывать окно.

Comment: @pnp2000, а Вы через `declarartive` делаете? Если да, то там немного по другому, но суть сохраняется.

Comment: @pnp2000, типа `mw.Show(); mw.Run()`

Comment: Да, я делал через declarartive , на самом деле я пока с GUI ничего толком не писал, просто есть небольшая консольная тулза и хотелось бы её немного проапгрейдить до GUI версии, мне и консольная версия подходит, но иногда она нужна и простым людям которые не сильно продвинутые в плане ИТ

Comment: В общем основную идею понял, так что спасибо за помощь, думаю можно использовать этот пакет не только для тестов но уже и в небольшой бой его пустить :)